# Recommend Linux software to scan multiple pages using sheet feeder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scanner

I use Ubuntu 9.10.  xsane works great for scanning a document placed on the glass, but I don't see any way to make it scan multiple pages using my all-in-one unit's sheet feeder.

I have the Brother MFC-290C and I'm using the manufacturer's driver.

The format scanned to is of lesser importance.  Ideally I'd like to be able to choose whether to have each page be its own file, or combine them into a multi-page PDF or TIFF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[gscan2pdf](http://gscan2pdf.sourceforge.net/) can do this. It's an excellent piece of software. It can clean up scans with unpaper and trigger OCR.

Answer (score 6):

Xsane also supports this, in the main Xsane interface select Multipage (or Ctrl+M) instead of Viewer which is the default. It opens a new dialog titled "xsane multipage project". Specify location where you want images saved, click "Create Project". Go Back to the main Xsane interface and scan as you would normally do, at the end of every scan it adds something like image-000x to the "project" dialog. When done with your documents, simply click "Save multipage file".

gscan2pdf is a nice software too, however I prefer to scan the batches in Xsane (appears clearer) and the import the images with gscan2pdf which helps create smaller PDFs.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that the next time I have a big scanning project.

Comment: This way you still have to scan each single page manually and then merge the result. The question was about doing this process automatically I guess.

Comment: no, it does work with page feeder

Answer (score 0):

xsane seems to only save to individual files - one for each page. I use gscan2pdf which does save to a multi-page pdf.